# TypeScript does not discern that my argument is an object

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function to extract a value from an input. This input can be either the value itself (a `number`, a `string`, `null`, etc. anything except an object) or an object. If it's an object, it can have a "value" property which will contain the value (again, a `number`, a `string`, `null`, etc. anything except an object).

I'm trying to write this function in TypeScript, but it keeps complaining:

```js
const extractValue = <T>(input: T | { value?: T, [k: string]: unknown }): T | undefined => {
  if (typeof input === "object" && input.value) { // Error: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'T | { value?: T | undefined; }'.   Property 'value' does not exist on type 'T'.
    return input.value;
  } else {
    return input; // Type 'T | { value?: T | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'T | undefined'.   Type '{ value?: T | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.     'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{ value?: T | undefined; }'.
  }
};
```

I would except TypeScript to detect in the first if statement that the input is not of type T, so it can have a value property, and that in the else part of the statement, it's gonna return something of type T.

Comment: Use `&` instead of `|`: `T & { value?: … }`

Comment: Thanks! It stops complaining but I'm not sure I understand. Wouldn't that mean that if `T` is, for example, a `number`, the input is of type `number` AND an `object` with an optional value property?

Comment: Unfortunately with this solution it complains when passing the argument: `extractValue({ value: 3 }) // Error:  Argument of type '{ value: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number & { [k: string]: unknown; value?: number | undefined; }'.   Type '{ value: number; }' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: So it can be `null`?  `extractValue(null)` will cause a runtime error, won't it?

Comment: Why is `value` optional in the argument object? I mean, if you call `extractValue({})` it will return `{}` because it's an `object` without a truthy `value` property, but that's not what you want to return, right?  I'd think you want `undefined` in that case.

Comment: I guess [this approach](//tsplay.dev/m3aV1w) might be what you're looking for, where you [constrain](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to be primitive, as long as you *don't* accept `null` and you don't do that check for truthiness of `input.value`. If that meets your needs I can write up an answer, but maybe you want to [edit] your question to disallow `null` (or come up with something that would not blow up with `null`) and remove that truthiness check so that the answer is just about constraints, which is your primary question I think.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is famously full of quirks. `typeof null` returns `'object'`, so the resulting deduction of that test is that input is `object | null`.

But even then, typescript [will not expand a type based on property tests](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732). If you do this:

```
if (typeof input === 'object' && input !== null && 'value' in input) {...}
```

you won't be able to use `input.value` because the compiler still assumes its type is `object`. So, you have two options:

1. you can use a type assertion to tell the compiler "I know what I'm doing":

   ```
   if (typeof input === 'object' && input !== null && 'value' in input)
     return (input as any).value;
   ```
2. you can use a type guard to hint what a runtime test means:

   ```
   function isValue(input: any): input is { value: any } { 
     return typeof input === 'object' && input !== null && 'value' in input;
   }

   /*...*/

   if (isValue(input)) 
     return input.value; // ok, we've hinted the compiler
   ```

Finally, you have to tell the compile what the return value is. I tried to use a conditional type

```
function extractValue<T>(input: T): T extends { value: infer U } ? U : T
```

But I get type mismatch errors trying to return values. Typescript appears to have some issues with mixing generics and conditional return types which are tracked by this issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014

So, since really our function can return any value, we can work around it with overloads. Overloads let you conditionally type the return value based on the function signature:

```
function extractValue<T>(input: { value: T }): T; // specific case
function extractValue<T>(input: T): T;            // general case
function extractValue(input: any) { /* actual logic */ }
```

Now it works and reports the correct types:

```
function isValue(input: any): input is { value: any } { 
  return typeof input === 'object' && input !== null && 'value' in input;
}

function extractValue<T>(input: { value: T }): T
function extractValue<T>(input: T): T
function extractValue<T>(input: T): any {
  if (isValue(input))
    return input.value;
  return input;
}

const a:number = extractValue(42);
const b:number = extractValue({ value: 42 });
const c:object = extractValue({ noValue: 42 });
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgNQIYBsQFMAUMYADiFAFyIZgCeAlJUaVMiogN6IBu2el1NRAF8OiALAAoRIgBOuKCBlIoNYrjjBkJMogC8+xAHI4AIwBWuaIcQAyG1uaIAhAbAgsWW-cM8cua0QOZADckkKSkqCQsAiIuAAeUDIY0Jh+ADwAKgB8hNoUor58iJnCDCWR4NDwSAlJKVBpeFm5TGSUmeWZldE1cYnJqby4LXnMHeUCHJLSMJqE6MNjZHR0M9Ky8opIbVAAdEW4oVKbCkpBUMfhEpIQCCgsGHr99UN++AAsAEx0x3dgD0QJmedUGjSWnEOlG+ZT+9xYEBBAwaTQInDAcFR0K+sMkQA)